# ゲルト - means money or not?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I found it in a dictionary but I'm not sure if actually means money.

Do Japanese people use this word?

Answer (score 2):

「ゲルト」 is a pre-World War II slang term meaning "money".  It comes from the German word "Geld".  The shorter form 「ゲル」 was also used.

Do we still use the word?  No, we do not unless some elderly are still secretly using it.  (You will see the word, however, if you read novels from a few decades ago.)

We now mostly use 「金{かね}」、「お金{かね}」、「金銭{きんせん}」, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese people don't use the term ゲルト but use お金 as money. Geld(ゲルト) means money in Germany.

Comment: ゲルト is Gel**d** in German, right? (not Gel**t**)

Comment: I made a spelling mistake. Geld is correct and it indeed means  money in Germany.